# R - sum values if string contains part of a column

Tags: r, sum

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame( word = c("house, garden, flower", "flower, red", "garden, tree, forest", "house, window, door, red"),
                  value = c(10,12,20,5),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Now I would like to sum up the values for each single word. This means the table should look like this:

```
word   | value
house  | 15
garden | 30
flower | 22
...
```

I could not find a solution by now. Does anybody has a solution?

Comment: One option could be `library(data.table) ; setDT(df1)[, .(unlist(tstrsplit(word, ", ", fixed = TRUE)), value)][, sum(value), by = V1]`

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not a duplocate @A.Suliman. I do not want to summerize it by the complete column "word", but only for a part, this means only for "house" of the full column "house, garden, flower"

Comment: @DavidArenburg, this works! Thanks so much!

Comment: @nississippi Sorry, flag retracted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using `unnest_tokens` from the `tidytext` library:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df1 %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, word) %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value))
```

Comment: this is perfect - short an easy to understand :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the words to sum up using `strsplit` then use `sapply` to sum up by the word.

```
Words = unique(unlist(strsplit(df1$word, ",\\s*")))
sapply(Words, function(w) sum(df1$value[grep(w, df1$word)]))
 house garden flower    red   tree forest window   door 
    15     30     22     17     20     20      5      5
```

Comment: Similarly: `tmp <- strsplit(df1$word, ", "); tapply(rep(df1$value, lengths(tmp)), unlist(tmp), sum)`

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to separate `word` column in multiple columns using `splitstackshape::cSplit` and then use `tidyr::gather`. Finally process data in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

df1%>% cSplit("word", sep = ",", stripWhite = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("word")), funs(as.character)) %>%
  gather(key, word, -value) %>%
  filter(!is.na(word)) %>%
  group_by(word) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  as.data.frame()


#     word value
# 1   door     5
# 2 flower    22
# 3 forest    20
# 4 garden    30
# 5  house    15
# 6    red    17
# 7   tree    20
# 8 window     5
```

Comment: @I think `splitstackshape::cSplit` would have been better option. As that would not been dependent on `number of columns` word would divide.